# segmentation fault (core dumped) and position of pointer's declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, g++

The following code runs properly with g++ compiler:

```
int ti = 72;
int *pooh = &ti;
std::cout<<*pooh; 
int i,*p,*q,*r;
int &j = i;       
i  = 36;
p  = &i;         
*q = i;          


std::cout<<"i: ( "<<i<<" , "<<&i<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"j: ( "<<j<<" , "<<&j<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"p: ( "<<*p<<" , "<<p<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"q: ( "<<*q<<" , "<<q<<" ) "<<std::endl<<std::endl;

j = 107;

std::cout<<"i: ( "<<i<<" , "<<&i<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"j: ( "<<j<<" , "<<&j<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"p: ( "<<*p<<" , "<<p<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"q: ( "<<*q<<" , "<<q<<" ) "<<std::endl;
```

but then changing the position of ti pointer declaration gives segmentation fault (core dumped):

```
int i,*p,*q,*r;
int &j = i;       //shallow copy , referencing , j is an alias of i
i  = 36;
p  = &i;          //shallow copy , referencing , p is an alias of i
*q = i;           //deep copy  , value copied after deferencing stored in seperated memory in stack
int ti = 72;
int *pooh = &ti;
std::cout<<*pooh; 

std::cout<<"i: ( "<<i<<" , "<<&i<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"j: ( "<<j<<" , "<<&j<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"p: ( "<<*p<<" , "<<p<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"q: ( "<<*q<<" , "<<q<<" ) "<<std::endl<<std::endl;

j = 107;

std::cout<<"i: ( "<<i<<" , "<<&i<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"j: ( "<<j<<" , "<<&j<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"p: ( "<<*p<<" , "<<p<<" ) "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"q: ( "<<*q<<" , "<<q<<" ) "<<std::endl;
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: `*q = i;` But at this point `q` never points anywhere. You have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `*q = i;` is asking for trouble, since the pointer hasn't got storage for an actual value, so UB so anything could happen.

Comment: In order to debug this kind of problems, you should compile your program with the flags (IMO, at the very least!) `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -DDEBUG -g` and run your program `prog` with valgrind like this: `valgrind prog`. The first warning I get is the error on the undefined behaviour pointed in another comment `*q = i`.

Comment: _"Can someone explain why?"_  [Your compiler can, if you enable warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/TjaK59vdn).

Answer (score 2):

You got lucky the first time. Both versions dereference an uninitiliazed pointer `q`. Depending on what random value `q` has your program will either crash or do something undefined.

Comment: I would say that an error that goes unnoticed is the opposite of luck.